# Where does Wilfred Sellars stand in current curricula?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, terminology, analytic-philosophy

I realize this is more of a question about "culture" of philosophy and answers will be relative.

As an autodidact, beginning largely in the Continental tradition, it is sometimes hard for me to know whether certain ideas are undergraduate cliches in philosophy departments or somewhat more arcane and perhaps no longer part of a standard curriculum.

In particular, I am interested in applying Sellars' concept of the "manifest image" versus the "scientific image." This seems a very useful model for sorting out certain aspects of the phenomenology-analytical contradictions.

Are these concepts still regularly taught? Are "manifest image" versus "scientific image" ideas most grad students are fully aware of?

Comment: you know of speculative realism ok it's meant to have post graduate appeal [for better or worse]. there's very many blogs on it

Comment: Yes, Sellars, Austin, and many others were more familiar with Hegel & Co. than is often recalled. I know Sellars was bit of an outlier, just not sure if "manifest image" and "scientific image" concepts are well known or just recuperated by recent "spec realists."

Comment: that's an interesting use of "recuperated" why do you use it? spec realism is definitely an academic phenomena, whether or not it will last as long as some may like

Comment: When I read Brassier using "manifest/scientific image" from Sellars I just don't know if these are well-known, abiding terms still taught and widely read, or if Brassier fished them out, i.e., "recuperated" them from Sellars texts that have long since fallen out of academic favor. That's basically my original question.

Comment: People like Robert Brandom and John McDowell have certainly made his work current in analytic philosophy. Sellars is one of the greats.

Answer (score 1):

Speculative realism seems quite popular, and some of its more celebrated proponents use the terms "manifest" and "scientific image". It seems speculative realism is quite *well known*, and some of its celebrated proponents actually deplore its success at winning over "excitable graduate students".

As a "movement" I would *guess* it doesn't yet rival the prevalence of e.g. Deleuze studies, though it is similarly aesthetically and politically focused.

Comment: Yes, actually that's where I picked up on Sellars terms. I don't yet have a sense of what I feel about so-called "speculative realism," a term everyone seems to deny now as faddish, though its turn away from phenomenogly-hermeneutics is welcome and the "speculations" are... bold. So far, it seems like a few dramatic gestures. But the "manifest" and "scientific" framing is much older, and I wasn't sure if Sellars is an outlier or remains basic to Anglo-American curriculum.

Comment: yeah i can't claim to follow it at all, i just argue about random things on-line :/ i'd suggest finding taught programmes at the more prestigious anglo universities, and seeing if they offer an on-line programme structure that includes sellars